# How to Set the RTL mode for Label

Tags: c#, winforms, right-to-left

I have a Label on my form and it's text is `Title:`. When I set the RTL mode to my form `this.RightToLeft=System.System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes`, now it's text displayed as `:Title`.

Is there any property to set for Label to change the text as `Title:` in RTL mode or can I customize the text by manual?

**Note:** Problem is that `:` character displayed at first in RTL mode.

[image]

Best Regards, Prithiv

Comment: Create two labels: first normal with text "Title:" and then second with your dynamic text and `RightToLeft` set to `Yes`

Comment: Changing `RightToLeft` will not change the location of your label. But it shows the text as right-to-left. Also The RightToLeft property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. You can set `RightToLeft` property of your label to No, to prevent it from change.  What's your requirement?

Comment: Yes.Location is not changed. I need to display (:) operator at end of the text in RTL mode. Default behaviour is [:Title].

Comment: **What's your goal?** You can set `RightToLeft` property of the label to `No`. But if you want to create a right to left UI, it's not a good idea. It's not a correct way to create right to left UI. If both the RightToLeftLayout and RightToLeft properties are true, mirroring will be turned on for the form, and control placement and text flow will be right-to-left.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the concept of RTL. What it means is that the start of the text is on the right hand side and therefor the end of the text is on the left hand side. Therefor, getting the `:` on the left side of the text is the correct behavior for anything that displays the text as RTL.